# Options Menu activating wrong menuItems after changing related Activity

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Problem :
I have a simple App with just two activities : MainActivity and SetupActivity. MainActivity has an Options Menu. Clicking on the Options Menu's 4th option brings up the SetupActivity.
However, if the change the SetupActivity's layout file and add more widgets/views (of any type), the App builds fine, but the Options Menu malfunctions :

1. Clicking on the 4th option does not brings up the SetupActivity, but clicking on one of the other menuitem brings the SetupActivity (with the new widgets). Usually this is the 3rd menu item, but can be one of the others.
2. Other menu items do not do what they are supposed to do.

I've tried adding different types of views in the layout of SetupActivity, which does not work. Also, changing the minSdkVersion in Android Manifest does not work either. The problem persists. Also, searching the Internet did not bring up any related problems for me.

Options Menu creation in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inf = this.getMenuInflater();
        inf.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mnu_item) {
        switch (mnu_item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.mnuOpen :
                openFile();
                return true;
                
            case R.id.mnuClear :
                area.clearAllPlots();
                area.initPlot(true);
                return true;
                
            case R.id.mnuSys :
                Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                startActivity(setupIntent);
                return true;
                
            default :
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(mnu_item);
        }
    }
```

MainActivity's Options Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnuOpen"
        android:title="Open datafile"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnuClear"
        android:title="Clear"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnuPlot"
        android:title="Plot properties..."/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnuSys"
        android:title="Setup system..."/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mnuExit"
        android:title="Exit"/>
</menu>
```

SetupActivity.java

```
package com.babai.ssplot;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class SetupActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
        
        // Customize ActionBar
        ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setTitle("Sytem Setup");
        bar.setSubtitle("Setup system of equations"); 
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inf = this.getMenuInflater();
        inf.inflate(R.menu.setup_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Layout of SetupActivity.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/setup"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeadingType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="System type :"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FF6633"
            android:layout_span="6" />
    </TableRow>
    
    <TableRow>
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgroup1"
            android:layout_span="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb1"
                android:text="1D function"
                android:checked="true"
                 />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb2"
                android:text="2D function"
                />
                
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb3"
                android:text="Difference Equation"
                android:checked="true"
                 />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb4"
                android:text="Differential Equation"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>
<!--    
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHR"
            android:text="Range :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#33FF33"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_span="10"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>-->
    
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblHeadingEqn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Equations :"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#FF3366"
            android:layout_span="10" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEqn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Eqn. 1 :"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />
            
         <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editEqn1"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:layout_width="200sp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_column="2" />
    </TableRow>
    
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEqn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Eqn. 2 :"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />
            
         <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editEqn2"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:layout_width="200sp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
    
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblEqn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Eqn. 3 :"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_column="1" />
            
         <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editEqn3"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:textSize="16sp"
              android:layout_width="200sp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_column="2"
               />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Tried :
Adding more widgets to SetupActivity. Changing minSdkVersion from 19 to 25 and 11.

Expected :
Activity shows normally with the new widgets.

What Happens :
the Options Menu malfunctions :

1. Clicking on the 4th option does not brings up the SetupActivity, but clicking on one of the other menuitem brings the SetupActivity (with the new widgets). Usually this is the 3rd menu item, but can be one of the others.
2. Other menu items do not do what they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The RadioButtons in SetupActivity's layout were missing `android:layout_width` attributes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).